# C#/.NET Desktop App Based on Instagram's API (For Offline Use & No Database Connectivity)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, api, instagram

For my semester assignment, I want to make a simple C#/.NET windows desktop application that will call the **Instagram API** and use its **Photo Effects/Filters**.

But my professor has said that the app must be a **standalone windows desktop app** which means it **should not have any internet or database connectivity**.

**For example:** If a user selects an image/photo from his computer using the desktop application (that I want to develop), I want the application to show a bunch of instagram filters that can applied to that image (without internet or any database connection).

**My basic question: Is it possible for me to develop such an app that uses the instagram API but does not need any internet or database connectivity?** If it is possible, can you guys guide me? I have visited instagram.com/developer/authentication/ link but I am not sure what to do. **And if it is not possible**, is there any other way to make an app that applies some effects/filters to an image? Please help me out. Thanks.

*EDIT: I am still a little confused though. When we use intagram on phone, we use internet only when we want to upload a photo. Filters are offline features. So is there any way I can get these features from the API? As my teacher said I 'can use API but not internet' I assumed APIs can work without the need of an internet connection.*

Comment: i don't think so. Either you will need some plugins which do a similar job, or you have to develop your own filters. The purpose of APIs are to connect to them and send / get data. Without internet connection, that won't work.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I really appreciate it :) I think I will have to drop the idea of using the instagram API and just integrate other developed filters. Thanks again @benka :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement offline image processing, you would either need an assembly of the filters or the actual code. I don't think that Instagram provides such tools. But there are plenty of third party libraries out there for image processing, if that's what you are looking for. For instance the [AForge image processing](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/samples/image_processing.html).